# youtube-dl optimal video resolution within a max limit

Tags: youtube-dl

Typically youtube-dl aims to shoot for the highest quality possible. That's not always practical. Flip side I've seen was for minimum quality possible. That's not practical either. What would be a command to make youtube-dl find the highest quality format that is **within** a set limit?

Say: having resolution width equal to or below a certain value. See this example for available formats for a given video link:

```
youtube -F <link>
...
format code               extension  resolution note
2242414685833597ad        m4a        audio only DASH audio   21k , m4a_dash container, mp4a.40.2 (48000Hz)
572715713158985v          mp4        426x240    DASH video  216k , mp4_dash container, avc1.4D401E, video only
110928776481884vd         mp4        640x360    DASH video  420k , mp4_dash container, avc1.4D401E, video only
896314927220784v          mp4        854x480    DASH video  738k , mp4_dash container, avc1.4D401E, video only
313835759204486v          mp4        1280x720   DASH video 1372k , mp4_dash container, avc1.4D401F, video only
dash_sd_src               mp4        unknown    
dash_sd_src_no_ratelimit  mp4        unknown    (best)
```

I want to tell youtube-dl to choose the highest quality video stream whose width does not exceed 640 pixels. That would be the `110928776481884vd` in this case.

If its not possible to do with resolution width, we could do with bitrate. So in this same example, bitrate should be 500k or lower.

Note: This question is specifically for non-youtube videos from different providers having different kinds of formats. The youtube ones have standard format names so I've already fixed for that.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Read the fine manual:

```
   Format selection examples
       Note  that on Windows you may need to use double quotes instead of sin‐
       gle.

              # Download best mp4 format available or any other best if no mp4 available
              $ youtube-dl -f 'bestvideo[ext=mp4]+bestaudio[ext=m4a]/best[ext=mp4]/best'

              # Download best format available but not better that 480p
              $ youtube-dl -f 'bestvideo[height<=480]+bestaudio/best[height<=480]'

              # Download best video only format but no bigger than 50 MB
              $ youtube-dl -f 'best[filesize<50M]'
```

Comment: That is incredibly ugly. I have a hard time believing that software as advanced as youtube-dl does not have a straightforward way to get 480p video.

Comment: Made my life simple by adding to my `zshrc` the following: `alias ytdl1="youtube-dl -f 'bestvideo[height<=720]+bestaudio/best[height<=720]'"`. Now it's simply `ytdl1 -o <filename> <url>` for me.